# Oracle pivot - one table field split into rows and columns

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, rollup

I have an Oracle 12c table that looks something like this:

```
Name     Class        Type 
--------------------------
Alice    Math           S
Alice    Female         A
Bob      Anthropology   S  
Bob      Male           A
Charlie  Science        S
Charlie  Tennis         A
Charlie  Male           A
Do       Math           S
Do       Female         A
Do       Tennis         A
Elmer    Male           A
Elmer    Science        S
```

I would like to pivot the table to produce a report that looks like below. Classes of type "S" are rows, and type "A" are columns. And then count the number of people that fall into each category. For example, there are two people that are both Female and take class Math - Alice and Do.

```
              Female    Male    Tennis   Total
-----------------------------------------------
Math            2         0        1       3
Anthropology    0         1        0       1 
Science         0         2        1       3
Total           2         3        2       7
```

I am familiar with pivot and cube in Oracle but I am stuck with getting the Class field split between rows and columns in the report.

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation as following:

> ```
> SQL> with dataa(name, class, type) as
>   2  (
>   3  select 'Alice',    'Math'           ,'S' from dual union all
>   4  select 'Alice',    'Female'         ,'A' from dual union all
>   5  select 'Bob',      'Anthropology'   ,'S' from dual union all
>   6  select 'Bob',      'Male'           ,'A' from dual union all
>   7  select 'Charlie',  'Science'        ,'S' from dual union all
>   8  select 'Charlie',  'Tennis'         ,'A' from dual union all
>   9  select 'Charlie',  'Male'           ,'A' from dual union all
>  10  select 'Do',       'Math'           ,'S' from dual union all
>  11  select 'Do',       'Female'         ,'A' from dual union all
>  12  select 'Do',       'Tennis'         ,'A' from dual union all
>  13  select 'Elmer',    'Male'           ,'A' from dual union all
>  14  select 'Elmer',    'Science'        ,'S' from dual
>  15  ),
>  16  -- your query starts from here
>  17  CTE AS
>  18  (
>  19  SELECT S.CLASS AS CLASS,
>  20  COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN A.CLASS = 'Female' THEN 1 END),0) AS Female,
>  21  COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN A.CLASS = 'Male' THEN 1 END),0) AS Male,
>  22  COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN A.CLASS = 'Tennis' THEN 1 END),0) AS Tennis,
>  23  COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN A.CLASS IN ('Female','Male','Tennis') THEN 1 END),0) AS TOTAL
>  24  FROM DATAA S JOIN DATAA A  ON (A.name = S.name)
>  25  WHERE S.type = 'S' AND A.TYPE = 'A'
>  26  GROUP BY S.CLASS
>  27  )
>  28  SELECT CLASS, Female, Male, Tennis, TOTAL FROM CTE
>  29  UNION ALL
>  30  SELECT 'Total' AS CLASS, SUM(Female), SUM(Male), SUM(Tennis), SUM(TOTAL) FROM CTE;
>
> CLASS            FEMALE       MALE     TENNIS      TOTAL
> ------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
> Science               0          2          1          3
> Anthropology          0          1          0          1
> Math                  2          0          1          3
> Total                 2          3          2          7
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!

Comment: Now Thats awesome.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You have the destination "row" value and the destination "column" value in separate rows. In order to do a GROUP BY CUBE, you need to put them together in the same input row using a JOIN. So do a JOIN, then a GROUP BY CUBE, then a PIVOT. To keep things straight, use the GROUPING function to see when you are grouping "rows" and when you are grouping "columns". This becomes a lot of work, and you wind up getting NULLs in some places where you want zeroes. Here is the solution for curiosity's sake:

```
with data(name, class, type) as (
  select 'Alice',    'Math'           ,'S' from dual union all
  select 'Alice',    'Female'         ,'A' from dual union all
  select 'Bob',      'Anthropology'   ,'S' from dual union all
  select 'Bob',      'Male'           ,'A' from dual union all
  select 'Charlie',  'Science'        ,'S' from dual union all
  select 'Charlie',  'Tennis'         ,'A' from dual union all
  select 'Charlie',  'Male'           ,'A' from dual union all
  select 'Do',       'Math'           ,'S' from dual union all
  select 'Do',       'Female'         ,'A' from dual union all
  select 'Do',       'Tennis'         ,'A' from dual union all
  select 'Elmer',    'Male'           ,'A' from dual union all
  select 'Elmer',    'Science'        ,'S' from dual
)
, joined_data as (
  select s.class row_class, a.class col_class
  from data s
  join data a 
  on s.type = 'S' and a.type = 'A' and s.name = a.name
)
, cubed_data as (
  select case grouping(col_class) when 1 then 'Total' else col_class end col_class,
    row_class, grouping(row_class) gr_row, count(*) cnt
  from joined_data
  group by cube(row_class, col_class)
) 
select case gr_row when 1 then 'Total' else row_class end " ",
  "Female", "Male", "Tennis", "Total"
from cubed_data
pivot(  
  sum(cnt) for col_class in (
    'Female' as "Female",'Male' as "Male",'Tennis' as "Tennis",'Total' as "Total"
  )  
)  
order by gr_row, row_class;

                 Female       Male     Tennis      Total
------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Anthropology                     1                     1
Math                  2                     1          3
Science                          2          1          3
Total                 2          3          2          7
```

Regards,
Stew

Answer (score 0):

For this requirement, I prefer the solution by Tejash to the PIVOT demonstration in my other answer. However, I would suggest using ROLLUP instead of UNION ALL. Two lines are changed and the UNION ALL is left out.

```
with data(name, class, type) as (
  select 'Alice',    'Math'           ,'S' from dual union all
  select 'Alice',    'Female'         ,'A' from dual union all
  select 'Bob',      'Anthropology'   ,'S' from dual union all
  select 'Bob',      'Male'           ,'A' from dual union all
  select 'Charlie',  'Science'        ,'S' from dual union all
  select 'Charlie',  'Tennis'         ,'A' from dual union all
  select 'Charlie',  'Male'           ,'A' from dual union all
  select 'Do',       'Math'           ,'S' from dual union all
  select 'Do',       'Female'         ,'A' from dual union all
  select 'Do',       'Tennis'         ,'A' from dual union all
  select 'Elmer',    'Male'           ,'A' from dual union all
  select 'Elmer',    'Science'        ,'S' from dual
)
SELECT case grouping(S.CLASS) when 1 then 'Total' else s.class end AS CLASS,
COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN A.CLASS = 'Female' THEN 1 END),0) AS Female,
COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN A.CLASS = 'Male' THEN 1 END),0) AS Male,
COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN A.CLASS = 'Tennis' THEN 1 END),0) AS Tennis,
count(*) AS TOTAL
FROM DATA S JOIN DATA A  ON (A.name = S.name)
WHERE S.type = 'S' AND A.TYPE = 'A'
GROUP BY rollup(S.CLASS);

CLASS            FEMALE       MALE     TENNIS      TOTAL
------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Anthropology          0          1          0          1
Math                  2          0          1          3
Science               0          2          1          3
Total                 2          3          2          7
```

Regards,
Stew